# javascript embedded in html5 to sum input value by ID for type radio - checked validation

Tags: javascript, html

Good day, SQL guy here (0 experience with javascript) trying to create an online survey using html 5 and using javascript to sum the radio selections by input Id. For the life of me I can't get the sum by Id, I can get it to return the individual values but not the addition of the values by Id. Code as below:

```
</head>

<body>
  <h1 align="center">PERSONALITY TRAITS SURVEY</h1>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Section B</legend>

      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><label><strong>I am the life of the party</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s1" type="radio" value="1" id="Extraversion"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s1" type="radio" value="2" id="Extraversion"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s1" type="radio"
            value="3" id="Extraversion"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s1" type="radio" value="4" id="Extraversion"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s1" type="radio" value="5" id="Extraversion"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>

            <td><label><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I have little to say</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s26" type="radio" value="-1" id="Extraversion"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s26" type="radio" value="-2" id="Extraversion"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s26" type=
            "radio" value="-3" id="Extraversion"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s26" type="radio" value="-4" id="Extraversion"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s26" type="radio" value="-5" id="Extraversion"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label><strong>I feel little concern for others</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s2" type="radio" value="-1" id="Agreeableness"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s2" type="radio" value="-2" id="Agreeableness"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s2" type="radio"
            value="-3" id="Agreeableness"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s2" type="radio" value="-4" id="Agreeableness"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s2" type="radio" value="-5" id="Agreeableness"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>

            <td><label><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I have a soft heart</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s27" type="radio" value="1" id="Agreeableness"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s27" type="radio" value="2" id="Agreeableness"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s27" type=
            "radio" value="3" id="Agreeableness"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s27" type="radio" value="4" id="Agreeableness"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s27" type="radio" value="5" id="Agreeableness"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label><strong>I am always prepared</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s3" type="radio" value="1" id="Conscientiousness"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s3" type="radio" value="2" id="Conscientiousness"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s3" type="radio"
            value="3" id="Conscientiousness"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s3" type="radio" value="4" id="Conscientiousness"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s3" type="radio" value="5" id="Conscientiousness"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>

            <td><label><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I often forget to put things back in their proper place</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s28" type="radio" value="-1" id="Conscientiousness"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s28" type="radio" value="-2" id="Conscientiousness"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s28" type=
            "radio" value="-3" id="Conscientiousness"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s28" type="radio" value="-4" id="Conscientiousness"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s28" type="radio" value="-5" id="Conscientiousness"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label><strong>I get stressed out easily</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s4" type="radio" value="-1" id="Neuroticism"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s4" type="radio" value="-2" id="Neuroticism"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s4" type="radio"
            value="-3" id="Neuroticism"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s4" type="radio" value="-4" id="Neuroticism"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s4" type="radio" value="-5" id="Neuroticism"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>

            <td><label><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I get upset easily</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s29" type="radio" value="-1" id="Neuroticism"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s29" type="radio" value="-2" id="Neuroticism"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s29" type=
            "radio" value="-3" id="Neuroticism"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s29" type="radio" value="-4" id="Neuroticism"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s29" type="radio" value="-5" id="Neuroticism"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label><strong>I have a rich vocabulary</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s5" type="radio" value="1" id="Openness to Experience"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s5" type="radio" value="2" id="Openness to Experience"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s5" type="radio"
            value="3" id="Openness to Experience"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s5" type="radio" value="4" id="Openness to Experience"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s5" type="radio" value="5" id="Openness to Experience"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>

            <td><label><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I do not have a good imagination</strong></label></td>

            <td><input name="s30" type="radio" value="-1" id="Openness to Experience"> <font size="2">Disagree</font> <input name="s30" type="radio" value="-2" id="Openness to Experience"> <font size="2">Slightly disagree</font> <input name="s30" type=
            "radio" value="-3" id="Openness to Experience"> <font size="2">Neutral</font> <input name="s30" type="radio" value="-4" id="Openness to Experience"> <font size="2">Slightly agree</font> <input name="s30" type="radio" value="-5" id="Openness to Experience"><font size=
            "2">Agree</font></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </fieldset>
  <br> 

    <button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
        Submit 
    </button> 

    <br> 

    <div id="result"></div> 

    <script> 
        function displayRadioValue() { 
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""; 
            var ele = sum(document.getElementsById Number('input')); 

            for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 

                if(ele[i].type="radio") { 

                    if(ele[i].checked) 
                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML 
                                += ele[i].id + " Score: " 
                                + ele[i].value + "<br>"; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Id of an element in a html document is always unique. No duplicate ids allowed.

Comment: @user2063635 thanks for that, I will have to create a variable for each attribute then.